# Python Program calculating CSV data as Zero

Tags: python, csv

I have a code that reads the csv file and calculates the liquid output. it was working for previous csv files but now for an updated csv file it is giving output as 0.0. Can anyone explain any glitch in the code?

My code is below:

```
    import csv
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
    from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo
    import datetime






    #csv_file = csv.reader(open("C:\Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\DataLog.csv"))
    from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input
    class App(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)


            button1 = Button(self, text="Browse for a file", command=self.askfilename)
            button2 = Button(self, text="Measure The Urine", command=self.takedate)
            button3 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
            button1.grid()
            button2.grid()
            button3.grid()
            l1 = Label(self, text="Enter from date (2017/01/01)")
            l1.grid()

            self.userInputFromRaw = Entry(self)
            self.userInputFromRaw.grid()
            l2 = Label(self, text="Enter to date (2017/01/01)")

            l2.grid()
            self.userInputToRaw = Entry(self)
            self.userInputToRaw.grid()
            self.output = Text(self)
            self.output.grid()



            self.grid()

        def askfilename(self):
            in_file = askopenfilename()
            if not in_file.endswith(('.CSV')):
                showwarning('Are you trying to annoy me?', 'How about giving me a CSV file, genius?')
            else:
                self.in_file=in_file

        def CsvImport(self,csv_file):


            dist = 0
            for row in csv_file:
                _dist = row[0]
                try:
                    _dist = float(_dist)
                except ValueError:
                    _dist = 0

                dist += _dist
            self.output.insert(END, "Urine Volume is: %.2f" % (_dist * 0.05))


        def takedate(self):
            from_raw = self.userInputFromRaw.get()
            from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('/')))
            print ('From date: = ' + str(from_date))
            to_raw = self.userInputToRaw.get()
            to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('/')))
            in_file = ("H:\DataLog.csv")
            in_file= csv.reader(open(in_file,"r"))

            for line in in_file:
                _dist = line[0]
                try:
                    file_date =  datetime.date(*map(int, line[1].split(' ')[1].split('/')))
                    if from_date <= file_date <= to_date:
                        self.CsvImport(in_file)

                except IndexError:
                    pass






    root = Tk()
    root.title("Urine Measurement")
    root.geometry("500x500")
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

my csv file looks like this:

```
  2  2017/02/17      19:06:17.188
```

Comment: It would help to have a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. For example, get rid of all of the tkinter stuff.

Comment: First you should do some debugging. Are you certain that the code is properly reading the data, and that `row[0]` actually contains what you think it contains?

Comment: Please remove the tkinter tag if your question doesn't contain any tkinter-specific questions.

Comment: I solved the problem, in the **self.output** statement, i was using the wrong variable. should have been **dist** instead of **_dist**. Thanks guys.